# What went wrong with Umbraco version 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, orm, umbraco

I'm not that familair with Umbraco, but I heard that they did a big rewrite for version 5, and actually dropped it in the end because it didn't work out. Killing a lot of hard work.

That must have been a very hard decission, but there is probably a lot of lessons to learn about architecture decissions that might seem a good idea in the beginning, but doesn't work out in the end. Especially for other people working with the ASP.NET / MVC framework.

What where the main problems and bottlenecks plaguing Umbraco 5, and what other lessons can we learn from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some links that you might help you understand.

http://ayende.com/blog/156577/on-umbracos-nhibernates-pullout

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/1/4/umbraco-5-on-performance-and-the-perils-of-premature-optimisation.aspx

My opinion, though its not universally shared, is that not enough attention was spent on performance from the get-go. Performance still matters and its not something you can tack on at the end of the project when it doesn't run fast enough. Yes, you can waste time on a project doing 'premature optimizations', but not worrying about performance at all and hoping you can just magically optimize at the end can be worse, and in this case fatal to the project and almost to the company.

To their credit they have recovered from this debacle and now seem to really be hitting their stride. Kudos to Neils Hartvig for making the hard decision to throw away perhaps thousands of hours of work when it became clear that forging ahead was not an option.

Comment: I agree with E.J. on the issues, especially performance. The memory usage for even a basic installation was huge, which hurt a lot of deployments in the shared hosting space as even new installs were barely usable thanks to using most of the memory allocated. The team did a fine job moving forward, and Umbraco 7 has really turned into something very nice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm especially curious about some of the details around the performance issues

Comment: I'd also say that they tried to add way to much complexity, to what was a fairly straightforward bit of software. Things which had previously been pretty trivial were suddenly many lines of complex code, and that put a lot of people off.